# User's Email is nil - Firebase, FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

For some reason, when a user signs into my app, the email value returned for the user is nil. I am requesting permission to access the email by setting the `readPermissions` on my login button like so:

```
loginButton.readPermissions = ["email"]
```

However, when the user successfully signs in, their email is still nil. This is the code I use to retrieve the email:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
    var email = user!.email! as String //Shouldn't be nil, but is
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using "Multiple account per email address". Check your project configuration in the console: Auth -> Sign In Method -> Advanced
It is possible the facebook account may not have an email address (phone number account)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just checked and it is in fact using 'multiple accounts per email'. I can't get to my app to test this at the moment as I am away from my computer, but is this likely to be the problem? i.e. disabling this might allow me to return the email address?

Comment: For that case  'multiple accounts per email', the email is returned in the provider data array but not in the top level email. That is the expected behavior. You are also allowed to have multiple firebase user accounts for different providers with the same email. If you switch to single account per email, then you can't have multiple accounts per email, google and facebook accounts with the same email will need to be linked. Know that before you make that decision of switching.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved it. I simply set my app not to use 'multiple accounts per email'.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and the problem was that I forgot to set the OAuth Redirect URI on my Facebook App.

**On Firebase:**

1. Go to Authentication > Sign-In Method
2. Select Facebook
3. Copy the redirect URI (format should be something like https://.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

**Navigate to the Facebook Developer site:**

1. Select the Facebook App you created for that project
2. On the right-end side, go to Products > Facebook Login > Settings
3. Paste the redirect URI in the field: Valid OAuth redirect URIs
4. Save

This fixed my problem

Hope it can help someone someday :)